# No File > Install menu entry in v11?

Tags: installation, application

In Mathematica 11.0.1 for Raspberry pi, there is no File > Install menu entry.

Can you confirm this for other platforms (Windows, Mac, unix) ?

If so, how to install a Mathematica application, so that the documentation becomes available locally in the help menu ?

Comment: You do not need that function to install an application. Simply place the application directory into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`.  This is what the File -> Install menu item does as well (it also extracts zip files if necessary).  If the application comes with documentation, then there should be a `PacletInfo.m` file at the location `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/AppName/PacletInfo.m`.  Check this to verify that you have the correct directory structure.

Comment: However, I do not know if the Raspberry Pi version supports documentation at all. The built-in documentation is stripped (for good reason: it takes up more than half of the space in a Mathematica installation).  Perhaps all of the documentation browsing functionality is missing.

Comment: The File > Install ... menu item appears in V11.1.1 running on OS X

Comment: Also appears on `11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)`

Comment: Placing the application in $UserBaseDirectory/Applications allows to run the package (.m) but not load the documentation.  Mathematica 11.0.1 for Raspberry pi has no local documentation (the help menu leads to online documentation on wolfram.com).  Do other platforms have local documentation?